# select first-letter not in the before

Tags: css

Given this markup

```
<span class="something">world</span>
```

and this CSS

```
.something::before {
  content: 'hello';
}
```

I want to add CSS to capitalise the first letter that isn't in the before psudo element.
i.e. the `w` from `world`.

Initially I (somewhat naively) thought that the following would work:

```
.something::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase; 
}
```

But it actually capitalised the first letter of the before psudo element, and only that.

I also tried to apply `:not` but this isn't valid on psudo elements.

Is it possible to use CSS to capitalise the first-letter that isn't part of the before psudo element?

Comment: @0stone0 - Pretty much. I'm now somewhat annoyed that my google searches didn't reveal this post despite the similarity of the titles :(

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would do this with the `:first-letter` pseudo element, but you are using `:before`.

This inserts text *before* the actual content of your paragraph, rather than the *first letter* of the actual content, :first-letter would match the first letter of the :before content instead.

That means that instead of this:

```html
<p class="normal">
    <p:before>Former - </p:before>
    <p.normal:first-letter>F</p.normal:first-letter>irst character of this paragraph will be normal and will have font size 40px;
</p>
```

You actually get this:

```html
<p class="normal">
    <p:before>
      <p.normal:first-letter>F</p.normal:first-letter>ormer - 
    </p:before>
    First character of this paragraph will be normal and will have font size 40px;
</p>
```

Due to how CSS generated content works, I don't think there's a solution in pure CSS to reach the first letter of the actual content once you have inserted content before it.

As an alternative, you could use a span in place of the :first-letter pseudo-element, to which you can then apply the blue color, but that means you have to insert extra elements:

```html
<p class="normal"><span>F</span>irst character of this paragraph will be normal and will have font size 40px;</p>
```

```css
p.normal {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: blue;
}
```